# Redux Store Adds Duplicate Content and Navigation to Original Selection Produces Empty Array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement a Redux data store along with URL routing for my React application and I am running into (2) issues:

1.) I have a dropdown menu and whenever I select the original selection (as defined by the URL I navigate to) the data store produces an empty array. For instance if I navigate to http://localhost:3001/dash/programs/all, select Soccer from the dropdown and then select All from the dropdown the data array output will be [] and the chart will output no visualization

2.) When I select an item from the dropdown and then select it again the data concatenates and the chart shows the data twice. For instance if I click on Socccer and the click on Soccer again the array will have duplicate data.

Here are my files:

DataStore.js

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { DataReducer } from "./DataReducer";

export const DashDataStore = createStore(DataReducer);
```

Types.js

```
export const DataTypes = {
    RELEASE_FREQUENCY_DATA: "release_frequency_data",
    PROGRAMS: "programs"
};

export const ActionTypes = {
    DATA_LOAD: "data_load"
};
```

ActionCreators.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from "./Types";
import { data as phData } from "./placeholderData";

export const loadData = (dataType) => ({
    type: ActionTypes.DATA_LOAD,
    payload: {
        dataType: dataType,
        data: phData[dataType]
    }
});
```

DataReducer.js

```
import { ActionTypes } from "./Types";

export const DataReducer = (storeData, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ActionTypes.DATA_LOAD:
                return {
                    ...storeData,
                    [action.payload.dataType]: action.payload.data
                };
        default:
            return storeData || {};
    }
};
```

ProgramNavigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ToggleLink } from "../ToggleLink";

export class ProgramNavigation extends Component {

    render() {
        return <React.Fragment>
            <div className = "dropdown">
                <button className = "btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="programDropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Select Program
                </button>
                <div className = "dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="programDropdown">
            { this.props.programs && this.props.programs.map(cat =>
            <ToggleLink className="dropdown-item" href = "#" key = { cat }
                to={ `${this.props.baseUrl}/${cat.toLowerCase()}`}>
                { cat }
            </ToggleLink>
            )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>

    }
}
```

OutcomeCard.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ProgramNavigation } from "./ProgramNavigation";
import { ChartRender } from "../charts/ChartRender";

export class OutcomeCard extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log(this.props.release_frequency_data);
        return <div className = "container-fluid">
            <ProgramNavigation baseUrl = "/dash/programs"
            programs={ this.props.programs }/>
            <br/><br/>
            <ChartRender release_frequency_data={ this.props.release_frequency_data }/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

DataConnector.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { loadData } from "../data/ActionCreators";
import { DataTypes } from "../data/Types";
import { OutcomeCard} from "../outcomes/OutcomeCard";

const mapStateToProps = (dataStore) => ({
    ...dataStore
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    loadData
};

const filterReleaseFrequency = (release_frequency_data = [], program) =>
    release_frequency_data.filter(p => p.program.toLowerCase() === program.toLowerCase());

export const DataConnector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    class extends Component {
        render() {
            return <Switch>
                <Route path="/dash/programs/:program?"
                       render={ (routeProps) =>
                           <OutcomeCard { ...this.props } { ...routeProps }
                           release_frequency_data={ filterReleaseFrequency(this.props.release_frequency_data,
                           routeProps.match.params.program) } />} />
                <Redirect to="/dash/programs/all" />
            </Switch>
        }

        componentDidMount() {
                this.props.loadData(DataTypes.RELEASE_FREQUENCY_DATA);
                this.props.loadData(DataTypes.PROGRAMS);
        }
    }
);
```

ToggleLink.js (to highlight active dropdown selection)

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

export class ToggleLink extends Component {

    render() {
        return <Route path={ this.props.to } exact={ this.props.exact }
                      children = { routeProps => {

                          const baseClasses = this.props.className || "dropdown-item";
                          const activeClass = this.props.activeClass || "dropdown-item active";
                          const inActiveClass = this.props.inActiveClass || "dropdown-item";

                          const combinedClasses =
            `${baseClasses} ${routeProps.match ? activeClass : inActiveClass}`

            return <Link to={ this.props.to } className={ combinedClasses }>
            { this.props.children }
            </Link>
    }} />
}
};
```

ChartRender.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";

export class ChartRender extends Component {

    render() {
        const chartOptions = {
            chart: {
                height: 300,
                width: 700,
                backgroundColor: "#071f3b",
                type: 'spline'
            },
            title: {
            text: null
        },
            yAxis: {
            title: {
                "text": null
            },
            plotLines: [
                {
                    color: "yellow",
                    value: 42.0977,
                    dashStyle: "shortdash",
                    width: 2,
                    zIndex: 100,
                    label: {
                        text: "TARGET",
                        align: "left",
                        x: 0,
                        y: 15,
                        style: {
                            color: "yellow",
                            zIndex: 10,
                            fontSize: ".6rem"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
                gridLineColor: "transparent",
                labels: {
                style: {
                    color: "white",
                        fontSize: ".6rem"
                }
            }
        },
            plotOptions: {
            series: {
                label: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            },
            column: {
                animation: {
                    duration: 1600
                }
            }
        },
            xAxis: {
            type: "datetime",
                labels: {
                style: {
                    color: "white",
                        fontSize: ".6rem"
                }
            }
        },
            series: [{
                name: "Chart Title",
                data: this.props.release_frequency_data
        }],
            legend: {
                enabled: false,
            }
    };
        
            return (
                <div style={{width: 'inherit', textAlign: 'center'}}>
                    <HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={chartOptions}/>
                </div>
            )
        }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { DashDataStore } from "./data/DataStore";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import { DataConnector } from "./outcomes/DataConnector";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";

Highcharts.setOptions({
    credits:{
        enabled: false
    }
});

export default class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return <Provider store = { DashDataStore }>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dash" component = { DataConnector } />
          <Redirect to="/dash" />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  }
}
```

placeholderData.js

```
export const data = {
    programs: ["Soccer", "Baseball", "Football", "All"],
    release_frequency_data: [
        {
            "x": 1577854800000,
            "y": 72.5918,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1580533200000,
            "y": 28.2154,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1583038800000,
            "y": 43.2504,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1585713600000,
            "y": 24.7519,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1588305600000,
            "y": 85.1896,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1590984000000,
            "y": 77.4816,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1593576000000,
            "y": 11.1693,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1596254400000,
            "y": 15.9701,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1598932800000,
            "y": 28.0714,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1601524800000,
            "y": 4.4327,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1604203200000,
            "y": 98.512,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1606798800000,
            "y": 15.5359,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Soccer"
        },
        {
            "x": 1577854800000,
            "y": 80.9702,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1580533200000,
            "y": 76.2792,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1583038800000,
            "y": 63.0659,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1585713600000,
            "y": 28.0056,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1588305600000,
            "y": 24.414,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1590984000000,
            "y": 8.6725,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1593576000000,
            "y": 92.8561,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1596254400000,
            "y": 1.7665,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1598932800000,
            "y": 98.9164,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1601524800000,
            "y": 22.7252,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1604203200000,
            "y": 35.0828,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1606798800000,
            "y": 49.46,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Baseball"
        },
        {
            "x": 1577854800000,
            "y": 34.8677,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1580533200000,
            "y": 55.0675,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1583038800000,
            "y": 25.5852,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1585713600000,
            "y": 98.1176,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1588305600000,
            "y": 91.8481,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1590984000000,
            "y": 62.554,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1593576000000,
            "y": 54.0914,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1596254400000,
            "y": 34.9944,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1598932800000,
            "y": 13.6009,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1601524800000,
            "y": 2.7292,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1604203200000,
            "y": 55.5105,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1606798800000,
            "y": 64.9702,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "Football"
        },
        {
            "x": 1577854800000,
            "y": 25.0526,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1580533200000,
            "y": 79.5283,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1583038800000,
            "y": 88.3788,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1585713600000,
            "y": 72.801,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1588305600000,
            "y": 29.0157,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1590984000000,
            "y": 78.9862,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1593576000000,
            "y": 42.0415,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1596254400000,
            "y": 10.274,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1598932800000,
            "y": 7.1479,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1601524800000,
            "y": 24.364,
            "color": "#0bfc03",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1604203200000,
            "y": 88.4601,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        },
        {
            "x": 1606798800000,
            "y": 46.5574,
            "color": "#fc0303",
            "program": "All"
        }
    ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to the filter function. There was an issue with how the data was being parsed and required the following change:

ORIGINAL

```
const filterReleaseFrequency = (release_frequency_data = [], program) =>
    release_frequency_data.filter(p => p.program.toLowerCase() === program.toLowerCase());
```

NEW

```
const filterReleaseFrequency = (release_frequency_data = [], program) =>
    JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(release_frequency_data.filter(p => p.program.toLowerCase() === program.toLowerCase())));
```